# How to access MyViewHolder inner class views outside RecyclerViewAdapter?

Tags: java, android

I have a MyViewHolder inner class inside RecyclerViewAdapter inside Checklistitems class. I want access elements of MyViewHolder in method onOptionItemSelected().
Here, I have three classes, and because of that, it becomes more complicated for me.

```
public class ChecklistItems extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_checklist_items);
}

public class ChecklistAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter  <RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder  onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ChecklistChildViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
      
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return x;
    }

    public class ChecklistChildViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        CheckBox checkBox;
        ImageView delete, move;

        ChecklistChildViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_child);
            delete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_child);
            move = itemView.findViewById(R.id.move_child);
            delete.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){

        case R.id.edit:
            isEditChecklist = true;
            // My problem is in here
            // I want to set visibility of a delete imageView here, when I clicked edit button in the toolbar
            // I have created these objects in order to access the ChecklistChildViewHolder class but the third line below asks
            // for a parameter, I don't know what to pass

            ChecklistItems checklistItems = new ChecklistItems();
            ChecklistItems.ChecklistAdapter checklistAdapter = checklistItems.new ChecklistAdapter();
            ChecklistAdapter.ChecklistChildViewHolder checklistChildViewHolder = checklistAdapter.new ChecklistChildViewHolder();
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: You can access viewholder but Use interface or notify using a variable that's the best.

Comment: @GobuCSG could you share some code how to do it using an interface?

Comment: You want update all the items right. So call notifyDatasetChanged()

Comment: You should use `notify*` APIs in the RecyclerView.Adapter.

Comment: Hey buddy, What is the purpose... You want notify a item or all the items...

Comment: Otherwise you can access recyclerview scroll listener and recyclerview.findViewHolderAdapterPostion(). Get the postion using scrollListener

Comment: @GobuCSG have a look at my code again, please

Comment: @DarShan changed the code, have  a look at my code again, please

Comment: @LalremLianBTlung Shared the code, have a look at it.

Comment: Hey buddy, My Ques is do you want update all the items or particular position after changes onItemSelected

Comment: @GobuCSG it depends, because I have a list of todo items, maybe I rename one item maybe more. Here my problem is that I can't access ChecklistChildViewHolder class in onOptionItemSelected. I don't know how to create an object of ChecklistChildViewHolder outside ChecklistAdapter.

Comment: @GobuCSG I want to access ChecklistChildViewHolder in onOptionItemSelected in order to make access this ( delete.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); ) and make it ( delete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: It's okay.. For all the items or single item?

Comment: @GobuCSG Please read the code again. My problem is getting access to ChecklistChildViewHolder inside onOptionItemSelected(); I just want to set the Visibility of all delete buttons from INVISIBLE() to VISIBLE

Comment: @Omer123 you want hide the button right.  try to understand you want hide an item or whole adapter items?

Comment: @GobuCSG have a look at this image https://ibb.co/sHss8Pv What I want is: when I clicked the option menu on the toolbar I want to show these cross (delete) image buttons to show in order to be able to delete whatever item I want to delete. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246082/discussion-between-gobu-csg-and-omer123).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code like this

Your Activity

```
public class ChecklistItems extends AppCompatActivity {

private ChecklistAdapter mAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_checklist_items);
    mAdapter = new ChecklistAdapter();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){

        case R.id.edit:
            isEditChecklist = true;
            mAdapter.updateItems(true);
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Your Adapter

```
public class ChecklistAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

private boolean isEnableDelete = false;

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder  onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new ChecklistChildViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    ((ChecklistChildViewHolder) holder).onBind(isEnableDelete);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return x;
}

public void updateItems(boolean isEnableDelete){
    this.isEnableDelete = isEnableDelete;
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}

public class ChecklistChildViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    CheckBox checkBox;
    ImageView delete, move;

    ChecklistChildViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_child);
        delete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_child);
        move = itemView.findViewById(R.id.move_child);
        delete.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    public void onBind(boolean isEnableDelete){
        if (isEnableDelete){
            delete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else delete.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your help, that is exactly what I want it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that. The `ViewHolder`s belong to the adapter. Just add a method in the adapter class to do what you want, in `onOptionsItemSelected()` call the method on the adapter. The adapter has direct access to all the `ViewHolder`s and can do whatever is needed.

Comment: Optimized the code. Check my code again. Don't know what to do.